# Calc: copy only a value, not stack number

Tags: kill-ring, calc

This seems so obvious that I feel sure that I've just missed something in the manual. I frequently do a calculation and then want to use that calculation elsewhere. But let's say my stack is currently:

```
--- Emacs Calculator Mode ---
1:  42
    .
```

Any way I've tried to copy the value `42` with incantations of `M-w`, what I get when I yank is

```
1:  42
```

including the newline.

The [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Killing-From-Stack.html) says

> Although a whole line is always deleted, C-k with no argument copies
>   only the number itself into the kill ring, whereas C-k with a prefix
>   argument of 1 copies the number with its trailing newline.

but that only works with `C-k`, weirdly, not with `M-w` (though otherwise the commands respond to arguments similarly), and still, that doesn't solve my problem, as I still get the stack number.

Amazingly, even moving the cursor, setting mark on `4` and point after `2` to set a region (which is highlighted, making me think this should work) doesn't get my the value: it still gives me the entire line.

I know about `M-x quick-calc`, which lets me enter an algebraic expression into the minibuffer whose result is placed into the kill ring, but that's not helpful if I'm doing a complex calculation or simply want to use the normal Calc RPN interface. (While there are methods described about how to move a `quick-calc` result into the calculator stack, I don't see a way to gain access to the stack from `quick-calc`. `$1`, etc., refer to prior results of `quick-calc` instead.)

`calc-copy-to-buffer` is bound conveniently to `y`, but I often want to use the result in the minibuffer or even in another program via kill-ring/clipboard integration, so this isn't a solution, either.

Of course I can yank or copy to a buffer and then edit the result and re-kill the edited result, but I do this so frequently and again, it seems like such an obvious use case that I really think I'm just missing something.

(I know there are Orgmode and database solutions for bulk transfer of Calc data, but I just want a single value to yank; it shouldn't be that hard.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just after posting this, I found a solution I'm surprised I didn't think of sooner:

1. Hit backtick (`calc-edit`) to edit the stack value.
2. Kill the line in the edit buffer with `C-w` (editing it first if it suits your needs).
3. `C-c C-c` to close the buffer (if you killed everything, the value gets restored on the stack, so it's equivalent to hitting `C-c C-k`).
4. Yank or paste wherever you please.

Not quite the single-key solution I was expecting, but it'll do.

Answer (score 5):

You can set mark and point, and save the region to the kill ring with `kill-ring-save`, which by default is bound to `C-M-w` in calc mode (instead of `M-w` as it is in most other modes).

Answer (score 3):

Using `C-x * y` allows you to yank the result into the buffer  of your choice, including the minibuffer. I'm not sure this will help you with yanking into another program, though. See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Yanking-Into-Buffers.html) for more.

Comment: Nice—I’m surprised I wasn’t aware of this and diddn’t find it in searching the docs. However, it does have one pretty drastic issue, IMO: if you use it from Calc rather than from the destination buffer, you can’t undo it—<kbd>C-x u</kbd> undoes the last Calc operation, not the yank.

Comment: Very useful to me because it only requires one key combination.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code to define a function to put the most recent thing in the calc stack into the kill ring.

```
(defun copy-calc-top ()
  "Copy the thing at the top of the calc stack."
  (interactive)
  (let ((val (calc-top)))
    (kill-new (if (Math-scalarp val)
                  (math-format-number val)
                (math-format-flat-expr-fancy val 0)))))
```

And we can bind it to a key.

```
(define-key calc-mode-map (kbd "M-w") #'copy-calc-top)
```

I think this should now work for most data types. It works for integers, floating point numbers, and dates.

Comment: Since the thing I use this for most frequently is date calculations, this wouldn't work for my purposes. I actually went down that road trying to define a function, but trying to make it general purpose by chaining a bunch of type-checking predicates was murder, so I gave up.

Comment: Btw, @zck, I tried to edit your answer to fix the missing close quote in the second line of the block, but I can't make an edit unless it's > 6 characters.

Comment: @Trey Thanks for pointing out the open string. I fixed it. Also, I just found #'math-format-flat-expr-fancy, which works for dates. I think it should work for most things.

Comment: This is excellent! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I thought exactly the same thing, found nothing and wrote this piece of code:

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load 'calc
  (defun calc-copy-as-kill ()
    "Copy the top of stack as kill."
    (interactive)
    (let ((buffer (generate-new-buffer "*copy-here*")))
      (unwind-protect
          (progn
            (cl-letf
                (((symbol-function 'calc-find-writable-buffer)
                  (lambda (buf mode) buffer)))
              (call-interactively 'calc-copy-to-buffer))
            (with-current-buffer buffer
              (kill-new (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max))))
            (message "Copied the result: %s" (car kill-ring)))
        (and (buffer-name buffer)
             (kill-buffer buffer)))))

  (defun calc-copy-as-kill-and-quit ()
    "Copy the top of stack as kill and quit."
    (interactive)
    (calc-copy-as-kill)
    (calc-quit))

  (define-key calc-mode-map (kbd "W")       'calc-copy-as-kill)
  (define-key calc-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") 'calc-copy-as-kill-and-quit))
```

This is kind of a dirty hack to steal what `calc-copy-to-buffer` would paste into the last buffer and copy it as kill, but it works for me so far.